# Add new auto increment column to existing table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, mysql-error-1068

My old migration is:

```
Schema::create('item_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->primary(['item_id', 'tag_id']);

});
```

Now I want add new auto increment column to this and drop old primary key

I try this:

```
Schema::table('item_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->unsignedInteger('id', true)->first();

    $table->dropPrimary();
    $table->primary('id');

});
```

But I have a error after migrate:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple
> primary key defined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drop the primary key in a separate migration and remove `$table->primary('id')`. Adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column automatically creates a primary key:

```php
Schema::table('item_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {   
    $table->dropPrimary();
});

Schema::table('item_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('id', true)->first();
});
```

You can also simplify the second migration:

```php
Schema::table('item_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->first();
});
```

Comment: what if you wanted to add another `unique auto incrementing id` without deleting `primary key`

Comment: @Liberi That's not possible, the `auto-incrementing` id needs to be the primary key.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir will this generate auto-increment values or do we have to run a custom `UPDATE` to have proper increment ID values after we add an `id` auto-increment to a pivot table that didn't have a primary key at all; for example I have a pivot table counting 100 rows with Users/Groups having 2 columns `user_id` and `group_id`, now I want to add an `id` auto-increment column and auto-fill all these ID values from 1 to 100 within my migration; will something like this do the job?

Comment: @ChristosLytras What DBMS are you using? Auto-increment values are definitely generated on MySQL/MariaDB.