# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I try to delete a row from my db but I can't access to it since I've not an ID colmun and 2 primary keys as you can see below:

Trying to delete:

```
$follow = Follow::where('follower', Auth::id())->where('follows', $id)->get()->first();
$follow->delete();
```

My migration:

```
Schema::create('followed_by', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('follower')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('follows')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('follower')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('follows')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->primary(['follower', 'follows']);
 });
```

So I don't know how can I access to it since I don't know which primary key I suppose to define in my model (I've tried twice)

Comment: What about just `Follow::where('follower', Auth::id())->where('follows', $id)->delete()`? I think you doesn't need to retrieve a record to delete it.

Comment: Same thing @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Another option would be to use DB Query Builder instead of Eloquent, something like this:  `DB::table('followed_by')->where('follower', Auth::id())->where('follows', $id)->delete()`. But if you are going to use relationships and other Eloquent functions, it would be best if you declare a single primary key called `id` as conventionally used in Laravel. It's really simple, just change this line `$table->primary(['follower', 'follows']);` to this one `$table->increments('id');` in your migration. I think that will make things easier for you in the future.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I can't modify my migration without must fresh my db... I can't find any specification on the Laravel doc to make a new migration then specify inside to change this

Comment: You can find how drop the primary keys on the Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#dropping-indexes), So, you can create a new migration, and add `Schema::table('followed_by', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary();
 });
 Schema::table('followed_by', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->first();
 });`, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788515/7498116).

Comment: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'PRIMARY': needed in a foreign key constrain
When I try to drop primaries. But I can't make a cascade like specified in the Laravel doc because it's a user on the other side of the foreign key

Comment: I did some tests and this worked for me in laravel 7 and a mysql 5.7 db: `Schema::table('followed_by', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->dropForeign(['follower']); $table->dropForeign(['follows']); $table->dropPrimary(); });
        Schema::table('followed_by', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id')->first(); $table->foreign('follower')->references('id')->on('users'); $table->foreign('follows')->references('id')->on('users'); });` You can give it a try, I don't have a laravel 5.6 project to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest still having an ID and use it as a primary key. You can set multiple primary key in the model but it's not always working as expected. If you wish you could try to add  protected $primaryKey = ['follower', 'follows']; but I think you will have some other issues in the future even if this works.

Comment: That's doesn't work, I've already try badly

Comment: So use id column as primary key and everything should be ok.

Comment: I don't have id row in my table and I can't add one since I can't delete my primaries keys anymore